Can anyone explain the constant in this relation
When the following function is plotted in desmos,
$$y^x = \frac{(xy)^y}{k},$$
Graph where $k = 1$, i.e. $y^x = (xy)^y$.
As k approaches the number $\approx 2.89473713041139$ ($1/k \approx 0.345454511048)$, the graph can be seen to converge at a point.
Graph converging at point.
As well as I can understand, this number doesn't hold any real significance, and so I am wondering what causes this number to make the graph converge. I attempted to use the Lambert W function, but was unable to make any real progress.
Thanks,
Nathan

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

For k<2.89 and k>2.9 you have two branches in the region around this "point" the function is not defind. so I would not call this common point of the branches as converge.

Let $f(x,y) = (xy)^y/y^x$. The graph of $z=f(x,y)$ is a surface that has a saddle point near $(x,y)=(4,1.5)$, which is the intersection point in your second graph. The saddle point can (in principle) be found by finding the point where both partial derivatives $f_x(x,y)$ and $f_y(x,y)$ vanish. The vanishing of the first partial derivative gives the relationship $x=y/\log y$ at this point, but the second equation seems to not have a closed form solution (with or without using that relationship), even in terms of the Lambert $W$-function. Nevertheless, the joint vanishing of the partial derivatives can be used to calculate the point $(x,y)$ (and thus the value of $k$) very precisely, without needing an interative method like looking at the level curves for various values of $k$.

The equation to solve is simple looking;$e^{-t}-2e^t+t=1,y=e^{e^t}$ which is similar to the hyperbolic Kepler equation
